# Limit products by group of customers?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a group of customers called "Resellers" I need limit the quantity of products that these customers can buy to 7 units. I need this function and I don't know exactly where I should apply the changes in the code. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a module, for example: Yournamespace_Yourmodule. Then in your module config.xml file, add observer for event sales_quote_save_after:

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <sales_quote_save_after>
            <observers>
                <yourmodulealias>
                    <class>Yournamespace_Yourmodule_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>verifyQty</method>
                </yourmodulealias>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_save_after>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Create the Observer file, then add this code:

```
public function verifyQty(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
        $quote = $cart->getQuote();
        $limit = 7;
        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        $resellerGroupId = 3; //change to your reseller group id

        $needUpdate = false;
        foreach ($cart->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getQty() > $limit && $customer->getGroupId() == $resellerGroupId) {
                    $quote->updateItem($item->getId(), array('qty' => $limit));
                    $needUpdate = true;
                }

        }
        if($needUpdate) $quote->save();
    }
```